# Why is orderBy number ordering not working correctly?

Tags: lodash

I am trying to order my table, but this ordering is not working correctly.

Example:

```
let dataArr = [3257,327,313,315,312,316,317,321,326,302];
I am using => _.orderBy(dataArr, ['number'], ['asc']) => [302,312,313,315,316,317,321,3257,326,327]
```

Why it isn't return like this [302,312,313,315,316,317,321,326,327,3257]?

How can I figure this problem out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this,

```
let dataArr = [3257,327,313,315,312,316,317,321,326,302];
_.orderBy(dataArr)
```

This will return your expected result. It is a simple array so you don't need to give it as a number type or order[asc/desc]. By default, it takes asc order.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "iteratees" argument. Since numbers don't have an "asc" property, this call does nothing. You should use the `_.identity` iterattee there:

```js
_.orderBy(dataArr, [_.identity], ['asc']) 
// Here -----------^
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik,

Thank you for your answer, But I tried this. It doesn't solve this problem :(

Comment: @burakkp works fine on my setup. What result are you getting with this call?

Comment: This usage getting array like this order => [302,312,313,315,316,317,321,3257,326,327] 

I am expecting like this => [302,312,313,315,316,317,321,326,327,3257]

Comment: @burakkp That's not what I'm getting on my setup. Are you sure the array isn't made of strings? What version are you using?

Comment: I am using latest version. It's looking like number by number for example It's return this => [302,312,313,315,316,317,321,3257,326,327], Probably It's looking first 3 number. I didn't understand why.

Comment: @burakkp are your numbers actually strings?

Comment: Sorry, I checked now. It's return string :(